# Installing PyGraphViz on Windows, Python 2.7

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I can't install pygraphviz on Windows XP. I'm using Python27.

Before to launch the setup I've changet these two variables of the setup.py file

```
library_path="C:\\Archivos de programa\\Graphviz 2.28\\bin"
include_path="C:\\Archivos de programa\\Graphviz 2.28\\include\\graphviz"
```

Then I've launched the setup. I'm using mingw32 as a compiler. I don't know what can I do now. I'm using the following command:

```
C:\Python27\pygraphviz-1.1>c:\python27\python setup.py build -c mingw32
```

And I've got the folling result

```
library_path=C:\Archivos de programa\Graphviz 2.28\bin
include_path=C:\Archivos de programa\Graphviz 2.28\include\graphviz
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-IC:\Archivos de programa\Graphviz 2.28\include\graphviz" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python
27\PC -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.o
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c: In function 'agattr_label':
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2855:5: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.def
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 146, in <module>
    package_data     = package_data
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 531, in build_extension
    target_lang=language)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 741, in link_shared_object
    extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 260, in link
    target_lang)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\unixccompiler.py", line 218, in link
    libraries)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1121, in gen_lib_options
    opt = compiler.runtime_library_dir_option(dir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\unixccompiler.py", line 285, in runtime_library_dir_option
    compiler = os.path.basename(sysconfig.get_config_var("CC"))
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 198, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 170, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea on how to solve it over windows?

In other computer with Ubuntu I've installed without problems.

Comment: I have followed these [instructions](http://bullogger.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/) and managed to install pygraphviz on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to a bug in Python distutils library. Edit your "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\unixccompiler.py" file (line 285, in runtime_library_dir_option) and change

```
compiler = os.path.basename(sysconfig.get_config_var("CC"))
```

to

```
compiler = 'gcc'
```

Don't forget to change it back after you've managed to install pygraphviz :)